# "hidden" intentions

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I just really want to ask the other ways of saying "having hidden intentions". The word that I've been looking for is something which is synonymous with the "hidden" used in this context. The word is at the tip of my tongue and I just can't really seem to remember it.

Comment: Hi, Flaubert, can you write an example sentence with context where the expression would be used? It will help users write an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for ***ulterior motives***, where "ulterior" means "intentionally hidden" ([here](http://www.google.com/search?q=define+ulterior&sourceid=silk&ie=UTF-8)) and "motives" is broadly synonymous with "intentions".

Answer (score 3):

[Hidden Agenda](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hidden+agenda)

[Concealed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concealed) Intentions

These are less commonly used than *Ulterior Motives*, but they mean the same as **hidden intentions**.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes what is hidden in somebody's mind could be shameful, unavowable or hypocritical and thus this is a **veiled** intention.