# What do you call when you offer someone to help but they don't know that your intention for helping is for your own motive

Tags: intensifying-adverbs

Suppose i tell you i will help you in something. Or i offer you something as a gift.  You are delighted.  But you don't have any idea that i am not ingenuously helping you.  I have some sole-purpose with you

Comment: Aside from the question, are you aware that in written English, the pronoun "I" is always written as a capital letter? Many spell checkers correct for it, but it seems yours doesn't.

Comment: In that case you **have an ulterior motive**, where _ulterior_ means (according to the American Heritage Dictionary) "Lying beyond what is evident,  revealed, or avowed, especially being concealed intentionally so as to deceive."

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [hidden intentions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302581/hidden-intentions/302583#302583).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a noun that accurately describes this person (in every possible sense that yuo're describing).

As offered by **user252044**, "deceiver" comes close but is not fully accurate. "deceiver" would only be correct if that person **actively** lies or misleads the other person. If he instead simply **omits** his true intentions, then he is not deceiving the other person.

But there is a way to state that this person has secret intentions:

> He has a [**hidden agenda**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hidden_agenda).
>
> *noun*
> A secret or ulterior motive for something.
> *‘she feels there's a hidden agenda behind the proposed road’*

Your question does not explicitly ask for a noun that describes the person, so this seems like an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

That person looks like a double dealer:

> Double dealer  Also found in: Wikipedia. Dou´ble deal´er
>   1.    One who practices double dealing; a deceitful, trickish person; a person who says one thing and does another.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Double+dealer

Comment: "a person who says one thing and does another" does not apply here. The person described will still do the thing that he said that he will do, it's only the **underlying intention** of his offer that is different.

Comment: Well, deceiver and hypocrite seem to be more generic then...

Comment: Hypocrite doesn't apply. Deceiver _might_ apply but not necessarily (e.g. a drug dealer who gives the first purchase for free, is not **deceiving** his customer, he's merely trying to get them hooked). It depends whether you **actively hide or lie about** your intentions (= deception) or merely **omit** them (= not deception)